# Image downloaded with node is 209 bytes but the image is accessible in chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, download, header

I am downloading images through node. For the most part this is working correctly, however some images are being saved with `209 bytes`. But when viewing these images directly in Chrome the [images](http://www.sothebys.com/content/dam/stb/lots/GE1/GE1401/216GE1401_7BVQX_SCENE.jpg) open perfectly normally.

## Headers

```
headers:
connection: "close"
content-length: "209"
content-type: "text/html"
date: "Thu, 14 Mar 2019 00:03:39 GMT"
expires: "Thu, 14 Mar 2019 00:03:39 GMT"
mime-version: "1.0"
```

## Status

```
statusCode: 400
statusMessage: "Bad Request"
```

## Code Used

```
const download = async function(uri, filename){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.head(uri, function(err, res) {
      if (res) {          
        request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', resolve);
      } else {
        reject(uri);
      }
    });
  })
};

const downloadImages = async function (dirName, images){
    if (await !fs.existsSync(dirName)){
      await fs.mkdirSync(dirName);
    }
    await asyncForEach(JSON.parse(images), async (image, index) => {
      const fileName = `${dirName}/${index}.jpg`;
      try {
        await readFile(fileName)
      }
      catch (err){
        if(err) {
          try {
            await download(image, fileName);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        }
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 2 headers to your request:

```
Accept: image/jpeg
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Example:

```
request({
  uri: uri,
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'image/jpeg',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'
  }
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', resolve);
```

**EDIT** Some explanation

The issue is in the server, not in client.

Because in Chrome it works, you can try to mimic Chrome's request by copying all the request headers into node.js code.

Once the code is working, try to remove one by one to see what is necessary.
For me it worked with just the 2 mentioned

[image: Chrome DevTools]